# how does a Python api database connection work?

Tags: python, database, pygresql

I am starting to try an work with databases using Python. I am trying to understand the process when I connect to a database and get some data out of it.

I think it works like this: The Python code is used by the Python Api to access the Database Management System (PostgreSQL) which in turn access the database to get the required data.

Python code <-> Python Api (PyGreSQL) <-> DBMS (PostgreSQL) <-> database

But it might also be like this
Python code <-> Python Api (PyGreSQL) <-> database

Or something completely different. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for example at the [documentation](http://www.pygresql.org/contents/pg/connection.html#query-execute-a-sql-command-string) of the `query` method of PyGreSQL it says:

> This method simply sends a SQL query to the database[...]

So the Python API only generates SQL queries and sends them to the DBMS. I don't think there's an example where an API (in any language) would directly interact with the actual database.

Comment: Thanks, I am still a bit confused. I thought the DBMS sends an SQL query to the database (Not PyGreSQL to the DBMS). So if PyGreSQL sends an SQL query to the DBMS what does the DBMS send to the database?

Comment: The DBMS receives the plain SQL query and will parse, analyze and come up with a query plan that is given to the database engine. In the case of PostgreSQL you can find a more detailed explanation of this process [here](http://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql03.html) but it gets really, really technical.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I understand now that the database and a DBMS are more intertwined than I thought.